# Need help finding/traversing dom in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm sure this is a redundant question, but I've looked for an hour or so and come up empty-handed so was hoping someone could help...

Looking for a way to use JS (not jquery) to return the class of the li below when searching for 'Chicken' (or whatever the value is).

```
<li class='113252'>
    <span>Chicken</span>
</li>
```

So was hoping the javascript would return the li class when given the span value (in this case Chicken).

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to traverse the *whole* document and not use any libs that make your life easier?

Comment: `Chicken` is not a value, it is open text.  Attributes/properties (variables) have values, open text is just text.

Comment: it can be as simple as that: `$(':contains(Chicken)').closest('li').attr('class')` with jQuery! maybe you should use a library

Comment: @gdoron: if I could downvote a comment, it would be yours.  He clearly said "`not jquery`"

Comment: @ThiefMaster "So you want to traverse the document (just like any lib) and not add tons of unnecessary lines?" I reworded it for you

Comment: Is the formatting clean and predictable? I mean, are all <li>s written as <li class="className"><span>Keyword</span></li>? If so a regular expression may be enough.

Comment: @gdoron: I agree that a library would make things easier especially in this case, but by clearly asking not to use a library, we have to assume they've considered that option already.

Comment: @vol7ron. And I showed him how much easy it could have been. so if someone write him a pure vanilla js code, he could compare it to the jQuery code. Your comment was inappropriate!

Comment: Note that className can't begin with a number. it's an invalid HTML.

Comment: @gdoron not true, since HTML 4, at least

Comment: @gdoron Who says classes can't start with numbers?

Comment: @gdoron: please don't take offense, forgive my humor as I wasn't trying to be rude.  I wish implied two things by my comment 1) SO should institute a comment downvote (to 0) and 2) SO contributors (mainly newbies) seem to want to answer questions before reading them, which I took you for.  I understand the point you were making, which is why I'm sure that's the reason you chose to answer in a comment instead submitting an actual answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var spanArray = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i=0; i<spanArray.length; i++) {
    if(spanArray[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase() === 'CHICKEN')
    {
        alert(spanArray[i].parentNode.className);
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm more familiar with jQuery but seems to work in the fiddle linked here: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/fCzYc/2/ (Updated to include suggested `break;` after match)

You can add more type checking for the `parentNode` to ensure it is an `li` and so on, but this should get you started.

Also, I'm not sure at all how efficient this is in a big document.

**Edit**
Having read through some comments I have updated my code above to include the break as suggested by [ajax333221](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908879/ajax333221).

[Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850833/dennis) mentioned that it would be better to call `getElementByTagName` on the `ul`.
Given you can have an `li` without a `ul` I added it here as separate code as I'm not sure if the OP has `ul` tags.

Code querying against each `ul` (jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/EJNXB/2/))

```
var ulArray = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var parentFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < ulArray.length; i++) {
    var spanArray = ulArray[i].getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i = 0; i < spanArray.length; i++) {
        if (spanArray[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase() === 'CHICKEN') {
            alert(spanArray[i].parentNode.className);
            parentFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(parentFound)
    {
        break;
    }
}​
```

Comment: I was about to post basically the same answer, so here are some useful references: [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), [`element.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode).

Comment: Thanks for the links to the actual documentation. I'm spoiled by jQuery and this little exercise was quite fun to work out. I didn't realise how little I remember about javascript syntax, not using jQuery. I will be keeping those references close by :)

Comment: You could make it better by calling `getElementsByTagName` on the `ul` itself instead of traversing the entire document.

Comment: @François, I'm spoiled by jQuery too! I remember having trouble traversing the DOM "manually" because of unexpected text nodes and cross-browser differences in implementation. And jQuery takes care of all that for me, it's a bless! :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I wish there were less jQuery questions on SO and more strictly-JavaScript only questions for that reason.  I feel this community is becoming to jQuery/Prototype dependent

Comment: adding a `break` on that loop will be advisable

Comment: @ajax333221: I have added the `break;` and updated the answer to include that and an update jsFiddle link too. @Dennis: I also added a code sample if you would like to query against `ul` elements.

Comment: Thank you guys so so much!  I can't believe how thoughtful you all were to take the time to write this.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means fully complete, which is why you should seek a library, but it does two things:

1. recursively traverse child elements (starting with the document's BODY), to find the supplied text
2. recursively traverse the parent element to find the supplied parent element tag, once found it will return the class of that parent

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/bttQN/

```
function getParentClass(element, parentTag){
   if (element.tagName == parentTag.toUpperCase())
       return element.className;
   return getParentClass(element.parentNode,parentTag);
}

window.findParentClass = function (text,tagName){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    for (var n=elements.length; n--;){
        var foundClass = (function searchNextChild(el){
            if (!el.children.length) {
                if (el.textContent == text) 
                   return getParentClass(el,tagName);
                return;
            }
            for (var i=0, n=el.children.length; i<n; i++)
               return searchNextChild(el.children[i]);
        })(elements[n]);

        return foundClass;
    }
};
```

Example Call:

```
alert( findParentClass('Chicken','li') );
```

Comment: isn't `document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);` better than by `body`?

Comment: @ajax333221: there's a lot of ways to improve the above.  However, the above makes you non-reliant on the tag type, which makes it easier to change from a `span` to a `p` or just open text in the `li`.  The above does have many faults, which is why I was trying to say it's not fully complete, it's a starting point.